# Why opening multiple ports for an application?

Tags: networking

Some web application require several (ranges) of ports to be opened.

Eg. Torrents, freeswitch, skype etc.

I can't see any good reason why.

If 3000 and 3001 are opened, and half the traffic goes to the former, half to the latter, is the router going to process the network data faster?

Or is is to let the app work despite port 3001 being closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributing the traffic across multiple ports can give improved performance in some cases.

On the backbone there will often be multiple different paths between two endpoints. For example if each hop along the path is actually a redundant pair of routers each router would have two equally good choices for which next router to send the packets to. A technique known as equal cost multi path (ECMP) is used which is often implemented by calculating a hash of source/destination IP/port number and using that to choose which route to send traffic to.

If all your traffic used the same source and destination IP and port number it would all be sent along the same path, so you wouldn't benefit from the additional available paths across the backbone.

On the other hand since the torrent protocol already communicates with many different IP addresses and your traffic is only a tiny fraction of what is being sent over those backbone links you can expect it to already be quite evenly spread. So there is not much throughput benefit from using different port numbers in your particular case. So it might be they have a completely different reason for using multiple ports.

Comment: So despite the separation being logical and not physical, there is a performance gain in separating. This is quite surprising!

Answer (score 1):

That is a very basic question and generally best answered by reading the product documentation for that specific application. That should explain which ports need to be opened, in what direction and which protocols will be need to be allowed.

Most clients are hard coded to connect to a server on specific (default) port to access a service. When that port is blocked by a firewall they will fail.

When you need to open multiple ports in your firewall to support an application that means, depending on which direction they need to be opened, that either the application offers multiple services and/or the application relies on multiple remote services and each of those runs a specific protocol on a different  port number.

There are other protocols than just HTTP and HTTPS over TCP...